# Function will not run correctly when called from Textchanged Event where other functions/logic checks are made

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a function (below) called from within a TextChanged event, when the function is called on it's own it works as expected, but when I introduce a check on the length of the text into the same Textchanged event sub the VerifyContent function always returns false.

```
Public Function VerifyContent(input As String, VerificationType As Integer) As Boolean
    VerifyContent = False
    If VerificationType = 1 Then ' Type 1 is to check whether the value is a whole integer value
        Dim intValue As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(input, intValue) Then ' Explicit conversion using TryParse
            VerifyContent = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Tariff_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tariff.TextChanged

        If Me.Tariff.Text.Length <> 10 Then ' Use Length property and strict comparison
            Console.WriteLine("Length check failed.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If VerifyContent(Me.Tariff.Text, 1) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Content verification passed.")
            MsgBox("This works a treat!")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Content verification failed.")
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to actually debug your code. If you set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, you'll be able to see exactly what it does and why. Given that you're looking for a 10-digit number, the issue is almost certainly that the input is not a valid `Integer`. Given that `Integer.MaxValue` is 2147483647, more than 78% of 10-digit numbers will fail to parse. If you expect to use numbers that big then use `Long` instead. That's got absolutely nothing to do with the length check and everything to do with the actual input, which proper testing and debugging would have shown you.

Comment: It doesn't really look like you need to actually parse the input anyway, because you're not using the resulting number. If what you actually care about is that every character is a numeric digit then you can check that using `input.All(Function(ch) Char.IsDigit(ch))`.

Comment: OT: While assigning to the function name to return a value is not wrong per se, it is a holdover from VB6 and is generally considered bad practice in VB.NET. You ought to use explicit `Return` statements. Also, using magic numbers is also considered bad practice. In your case, that value `1` means nothing to anyone who isn't already familiar. You should declare an `Enum` for your verification type values. That way, the labels are descriptive and self-documenting but they are still numbers under the hood so are efficient to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue almost certainly has nothing to do with your length check and everything to do with the actual data. You are looking for 10-digit numbers and only a fraction of the possible 10-digit numbers can be parsed as an `Integer`. `Integer.MaxValue` is `2147483647` so any input that is larger than that cannot be converted to an `Integer`. If you expect to be able to use such values, you need to use `Long` rather than `Integer`.

That said, if you're not actually using the number you generate then there's probably no need to generate it at all. If what you care about is that the input is all numeric digits then you can check for that without converting anything:

```vb
If input.All(Function(ch) Char.IsDigit(ch)) Then
    'All characters in input are digits.
End If
```

A `String` is an `IEnumerable(Of Char)` so you can use LINQ on it to query the characters it contains. The `All` extension method returns `True` if and only if all items in the list satisfy the specified condition.

I haven't tested this in VB but, based on what works in C#, I'm pretty sure that this syntax would work too:

```vb
If input.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) Then
    'All characters in input are digits.
End If
```

Methods like `All` take a delegate as an argument, so you can use a lambda expression or any other delegate of the appropriate type. When called on an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, the delegate must have a single argument of type `T` and return a `Boolean`.

Comment: Thank you for the above, I knew it would be something simple I was missing (my input value is greater than the integer limit).